# Cannot run a single MySQLdb execute with MySQLdb in Python 3.2.3

Tags: mysql-python

I'm about to go nuts with python 3.2.3

Do you see something wrong with the following statement?

```
cur.execute('''SELECT hits FROM counters WHERE url = ?''', (page,)) 
data = cur.fetchone()
```

because as you can see by visiting my webpage at http://superhost.gr it produces an error and I don't know why.

I'm using MySQLdb.

Ι'm using '?' or '%s'; the latter used to work flawlessly with python 2.6, but it does not in python 3.2.3

Both these commands fail in python 3.2.3

```
cur.execute('''SELECT hits FROM counters WHERE url = ?''', (page,)) 

cur.execute('''SELECT hits FROM counters WHERE url = %s''', (page,))
```

Any idea why?

Comment: someone have an idea please?

Comment: What is the specific error that shows up at this particular line?

Answer (score 0):

I have never try MySQLdb on python 3k. You can read [the dev blog](http://mysql-python.blogspot.com/2012/09/a-brief-history-of-mysqldb.html):

> Python 3 compatibility is needed now more than ever. I thought I could
>   do this in 1.2.4, but I would have to sacrifice compatibility for
>   Python < 2.7. So MySQLdb-1.2.4 will be a bugfix release and fully
>   Python 2.7 compatible (and should be Python 2.8 compatible), and very
>   soon thereafter there will be a 1.3.0 which will require Python 2.7 or
>   newer and be compatible with Python 3.

Comment: Or format the string before execute query `cur.execute('''SELECT hits FROM counters WHERE url = ?''' % page)`  ?

Comment: Switched to 'pymysql' module and everything work as expected.